# How to determine onItemClick for pulltorefreshlistview

Tags: android

I am using a pulltorefreshlistview how can i determine onitemclick for it, the current code i am using is not giving me right position.

Thanks

Comment: Without knowing what specific pull-to-refresh implementation, it's kind of hard to give a concrete answer. However, I've seen some pull-to-refresh relying on a header in the `ListView`, so make sure you at least take that into consideration. If you're still unsure, just inspect the contents of the `AdapterView<?>` instance that gets passed into the `OnItemClick(...)` method. You can always retrieve the correct item for a position by calling `getItemAtPosition(...)`.

Comment: I have Erik Wallentinsen implementation..

Comment: The problem is its not giving correct onItemClick implementaion, when i click 0th item it gives me the 3rd one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already pointed out in a comment: you may be clicking on the first *visible* position on-screen, but that doesn't mean there aren't any hidden items or invisible headers that take up position 1 & 2.

Actually, after checking the [source code of the pull-to-refresh implementation](https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView/blob/master/libraryproject/src/eu/erikw/PullToRefreshListView.java), it indeed adds at [least one header](https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView/blob/master/libraryproject/src/eu/erikw/PullToRefreshListView.java#L219).

One solution would be to offset the position in `OnItemClick(...)` by the return value of [`getHeaderViewsCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#getHeaderViewsCount%28&29) (and potentially some other count). However, it is probably easier and more fool-proof to just call [`getItemAtPosition(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition%28int%29) with the `position` from `OnItemClick` and cast the returned object to whatever you're populating the ListView with.

Comment: i still not figure out..can you give me a example for using PullToRefreshListView?

Comment: @nullmicgo: Just call `listview.getItemAtPosition(position)` in `onItemClick(...)` (or `onListItemClick(...)`if you implemented a `ListActivity` or `ListFragment`) and cast the result to whatever you're populating the list with. That will take into account any headers and/or footers that may be added.